# Holomorphic line bundles on smooth points of a quotient

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, lie-groups, line-bundles

I am an amateur algebraic geometer, so maybe this question is trivial and if this is the case, then I apologize. This is a question that came up while working on something completely different.

Consider the vector space $M_n(\mathbb{C})^{\oplus d}$ it is equipped with a natural action of $G = \operatorname{PGL_n}(\mathbb{C})$. Every $g \in G$ acts by conjugation on the direct summands. Let $X \subset M_n(\mathbb{C})^{\oplus d}$ be the set $X = \left\{g \cdot x \mid x x^* = \sum_{j=1}^d x_j x_j^* < 1 \right\}$. Here $<$ stands for the partial order on positive operators. In other words, $X$ is the $G$-orbit of a Cartan domain of type I. $X$ is a contractible Stein manifold and thus has no holomorphic line bundles. Consider the categorical quotient $Y = X//G$ (by this I mean that $Y$ is the image of $X$ in the categorical quotient of the entire space) and let $X^s$ be the simple points of $X$. set $U = X^s/G$,then (at least for $n$ large enough) $U$ is precisely the set of smooth points of $Y$. Assume that $\operatorname{codim}\left(Y \setminus U\right) \geq 2$. My question is a bit general, but I would like to know what can be said about the holomorphic line bundles on $U$? More specifically:

1. How can one try and compute $H^1(U,\mathcal{O}_U^*)$? (I guess that one could write some spectral sequence to try and compute it, but I am not sure what can be said about the group cohomology of $G$ acting on $\mathcal{O}_X^*$.)
2. What is the relation between $\operatorname{Pic}(U)$ and $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)$?